# dplyr: NSE in joins (by)

Tags: r, join, tidyeval, nse

I had a hard time to figure out how I could join two tables using dplyr::left_join with NSE. The problem was that I could not supply the right value to 'by'. I think I have found a solution for now, but it feels like I am doing it in an extra complicated way. So, if you know an easier/more elegant solution, please let me know :)

That's what I am doing:

```
# some data
df <- dplyr::tibble(x=1:10,
                    y=LETTERS[1:10],
                    z=LETTERS[11:20])

# some function
test_fun <- function(df,id){
  id <- rlang::enquo(id)
  join_var <- names(rlang::quos_auto_name(id))[2] # is there an easier way?
  # not important: doing some stuff
  df1 <- df %>%
    dplyr::select(!!id,y)
  df2 <- df %>%
    dplyr::select(!!id,z)
  # join using prepared join_var
  df1 %>%
    dplyr::left_join(df2,setNames(join_var,join_var))
}

test_fun(df,id=x)
```

As I was asked for additional context and some more explaination to better understand my problem, I will try to give some more information here:

NSE is an abbreviation for non-standard evaluation. My goal was to build a function that joins to datasets based on a variable the user could define. The main problem was that the by-argument in dplyr::left_join did not accept the quoted variable (NSE argument) and so I had to find a workaround. The way I found (join_var <- names(rlang::quos_auto_name(id))[2]) seemd a little complicated and I was looking for an easier solution. That was - by the way - provided by Lionel Henry ... thanks :)

Comment: Please could you add some more context to what you are trying to do, with expected results so that others can figure it out and help (and what is NSE by the way)?

Comment: the `setNames` part in your example was what I was missing so thanks for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `join_var <- rlang::as_name(id)`.