# NSE dplyr::left_join failing due to incompatible types

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval, nse

I'm writing a function which helps me clean up field trial data. I'm writing it using tidyeval NSE to challenge myself and ensure that the function is easy to use if I return to it. I think I've nearly got it, but when running my test frame I get a failure, with the following message:

> Error: Can't join on 'plantid' x 'year' because of incompatible types
>   (factor / integer) Called from: left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y,
>   aux_x, aux_y, na_matches, environment())

At first it was suggested that this could be due to grouping, so I added an ungroup() before the joins, however the issue persisted.

Is there any way to fix this, without manually changing year to a character (?)
Many thanks in advance.

*Function*

```
id_injured <- function(df, plantid, year, injuries, forbidden_values, monotonic_increase=FALSE,height){
  #Converting variables in selectlist to character
  df <- df %>% mutate_at(injuries,as.character)

  #Parsing unquoted strings.

  plantid <- enquo(plantid)
  year <- enquo(year)
  height <- enquo(height)

  #Mark injured as 1.
  Dataplantid  <- df %>% mutate(is_injured = purrr::pmap_int(select(.,!!injuries), ~any(c(...) %in% !!forbidden_values)))

  #Find time of first observed injury.
  injuredlist <- Dataplantid %>% group_by(!!plantid) %>%  filter(is_injured == 1)  %>% summarise(firstinjury = min(!!year))  %>% ungroup()


  #In plantid group, all years older than first injury are marked 1, else 0.
  joinedinjured <- dplyr::left_join(x=Dataplantid, y=injuredlist, by = rlang::as_name(plantid))

  joinedinjured <- joinedinjured %>% group_by(!!plantid) %>% mutate(afterfirstinjury = case_when(!!year >= firstinjury ~ 1,
                                                                                                                     !!year< firstinjury ~ 0))

  returnvalues <- joinedinjured %>% select(!!plantid, !!year, firstinjury, afterfirstinjury) %>% ungroup()


  ##c() does not support rlang bangs (!!) but takes a string. Solution follows below approach
  # from Lionel Henry, Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518138/11550980 


  returnvalues <- left_join(df, returnvalues, by=c(setNames(rlang::as_name(plantid),rlang::as_name(year))))

#Mark all prior to a break in monotonic growth as true.
 if(monotonic_increase==TRUE){

    returnvalues<- returnvalues %>% group_by(!!plantid) %>% arrange(!!plantid, !!year) %>%
      tidyr::fill(!!height, .direction="downup") %>%
      mutate(monotonic_growth = cumall(c(TRUE, diff(height) > 0))) %>% ungroup()
  returnvalues
 }
  returnvalues
}
```

*Test frame*

```
 plantid <- rep(c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5"), times=c(3,3,3,3,3))
 year <- rep(1:3, length.out=length(plantid))
 set.seed(42)
 PrimaryInjury <- sample(c(NA,NA,NA,"Rust","Insect","Snow break"), 15, replace=TRUE)
 SecondaryInjury <- rep(NA, length.out=length(plantid))
 OtherInjury <- rep(NA, length.out=length(plantid))
 height <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,2)


 testframe <- data.frame(plantid,year,PrimaryInjury,SecondaryInjury, OtherInjury,height)

 rm(OtherInjury)
 rm(plantid)
 rm(PrimaryInjury)
 rm(SecondaryInjury)
 rm(year)
 rm(height)
```

*Running function - this creates an error.*

```
 id_injured(df=testframe, plantid=plantid,year=year,injuries = c("PrimaryInjury","SecondaryInjury","OtherInjury"),forbidden_values = c("Rust","Insect","Snow break"),monotonic_increase = FALSE)
```

Comment: How are you even joining by `plantid` and `year`? They don't have anything in common, they will not match anything.

Comment: @RonakShah are you saying that c(plantid, year) is interpreted as plantid==year? I am trying to express that each observation is uniquely identified by a plantid and a year combination, which is why I am want to join by plantid and year.

Comment: Then you should remove the `setNames()`, otherwise it will try to match `plantid` on `year`, which generates the error.

Comment: Thank you @tspano, my function is now operational! Add this as a comment and I will mark it as solved!